# How to get the size of a std::bitset from another class?

Tags: c++, templates

Im trying to create a class that has a `std::bitset` in, and another class is supposed to take it as a parameter and create an `std::array` getting the size of the `std::bitset` from the class. Like this:

```
template<size_t size>
class Individual{
public:
    std::bitset<size> data;
};

template<typename Ind>
class Process {
public:
    Process() = default;
    std::array<OtherType, Ind::data.size()> individuals;//Size of array must be the size of the bitset!
};
```

But of course this is not working (as you can guess, because `data` is not static). How to get the size of the `std::bitset` and put it into the `std::array` from the second class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that during the *declaration* of `Process`, it doesn't yet know that `Ind` is an `Individual`, so can't do much with it yet. Worse, `data` is not a static member, so `Ind::data` doesn't work without an instance of `Process`.  Luckily, there's tons of workarounds, based on your restrictions.

Size as parameter:

```
template<size_t size>
class Process {
public:
    Process() = default;
    std::array<OtherType, size> individuals;
};
```

Or tweak `Individual` to expose the info you need

```
template<size_t size>
class Individual{
public:
    static const size_t size_ = size; //`static const` is important!
    std::bitset<size> data;
};

template<typename Ind>
class Process {
public:
    Process() = default;
    std::array<OtherType, Ind::size_> individuals;
};
```

Or as partial specialization:

```
template<typename Ind>
class Process {
   static_assert(sizeof(T)==0, "param must be of type Individual")
   //or whatever you want for non-Individual parameters
};
template<size_t size>
class Process<Individual<size>> {
public:
    Process() = default;
    std::array<OtherType, size> individuals;
};
```

Or use a partially specialized helper class:

```
template<class T>
struct size_helper {
   static_assert(sizeof(T)==0, "must specialize size_helper");
};

template<size_t size>
class Individual{
public:
    std::bitset<size> data;
};

template<size_t size_>
struct size_helper<Individual<size_>> {
   static const size_t size = size_;
};

template<typename Ind>
class Process {
public:
    static const size_t size = size_helper<Ind>::size;
    Process() = default;
    std::array<OtherType, Ind::size_> individuals;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a `static` variable.

```
template<size_t SIZE>
class Individual{
public:
    static constexpr auto size = SIZE;
    std::bitset<SIZE> data;
};

template<typename Ind>
class Process {
public:
    Process() = default;
    std::array<OtherType, Ind::size> individuals;
};
```